# Spark Caching and distributed computation

Tags: apache-spark

Suppose I want to load a 50GB of data to Spark.
I have 10 Nodes with 60GB of RAM each. What would happen if I will cache the data?

The data can be cached on 1 computer and do all of the computation on it,
But it would be much better for me to cache 5GB on each computer in order to distribute the computation between all of the nodes which will lead to a much faster work.

I'm loading data from S3. I think its relevant.

Code example:

```
val data = sc.textFile("s3n://bucket/file.txt").cache()
```

How would the data spread between the nodes after I will preform some actions on the data?

In addition:

What would be the difference between loading 100 partitions from HDFS, or loading the same amount of partitions but from S3? I less care about network at the moment.